# On Windows 10, why is my Ethernet card losing its default gateway when I change a static route to a host via that interface?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I have a dual homed computer (WiFi and Ethernet different networks)
I have an existing route, let's say to 1.1.1.1/32 via the WiFi adapter
When I try to change that using

`route change 1.1.1.1  mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1 metric 2 if 9`
(where 9 is the Ethernet adapter)

the Ethernet adapter loses its gateway settings

Using the ipconfig command I can see that now it has no def gateway

Comment: I've got the same issue. In my case, it is a VirtualBox VM running Windows 10 and LANCOM's Advanced VPN Client. The problem started occurring after installing the LANCOM client. It happens about once a week.

Answer (score 0):

To treat the symptoms, I am running the following PowerShell script in a (every 5 minutes repeating) scheduled Task (`10.1.2.121` is the IP address of the network card and `10.1.2.254` is the IP address of the gateway) to add the default gateway route again:

```
$nic = Get-NetIPAddress -IPAddress 10.1.2.121 -ErrorAction Stop;
try {
    Get-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $nic.InterfaceIndex -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 -ErrorAction Stop;
}
catch {
    New-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex $nic.InterfaceIndex -NextHop 10.1.2.254 -DestinationPrefix 0.0.0.0/0 -RouteMetric 1 -ErrorAction Stop;
}
```